# Insert distinct values from one table into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So for each distinct value in a column of one table I want to insert that unique value into a row of another table.

```
list = select distinct(id) from table0

for distinct_id in list
 insert into table1 (id) values (distinct_id)
end
```

Any ideas as to how to go about this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Whenever you think about doing something in a loop, step back, and think again. SQL is optimized to work with sets. You can do this using a set-based query without the need to loop:

```
INSERT dbo.table1(id) SELECT DISTINCT id FROM dbo.table0;
```

There are some edge cases where looping can make more sense, but as SQL Server matures and more functionality is added, those edge cases get narrower and narrower...

Comment: Would it be possible to create an "auto-updated" table just to store this distinct values. I.e., if they're removed or update at table 0, they would also be updated at table 1.

Comment: @Gabriel Sure, create an indexed view.

Comment: thank you, I'll search for this topic, creating indexed views of unique values. If they were unique dates of many "months", it would still be the same right? I'm talking about a sensor register that stores numbers each second. And I'd like to know which dates I have available to search inside.

Comment: @Gabriel Assuming you mean you want to count by day even though the column has time as well? `CREATE VIEW dbo.vname WITH SCHEMABINDING AS SELECT d = CONVERT(date, col), c = COUNT_BIG(*) FROM dbo.tname GROUP BY CONVERT(date, col);` then `CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cix_vname ON dbo.vname(d);`

Comment: almost as described. I have a datetime column, that could also be stored as date and time separately. And there are many (thousand) rows for each sensor, as they record each second, and for months. And I'd like to have a list of dates (days) that have data. Today, what I'm doing is searching for the whole table looking for distinct dates, each time I need this query. And I need it very often.

Comment: @Gabriel Suggest asking a question on dba.stackexchange, will be much better than trying to solve in comments here.

Answer (score 8):

```
insert into table1 (id)
select distinct id from table0
```

Answer (score 6):

The following statement works with me.

```
insert into table1(col1, col2) select distinct on (col1) col1 col2 from table0
```

Comment: This one worked for me perfectly for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The below query will also check the existing data in the Table2.

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Id) SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM Table1 WHERE Id NOT IN(SELECT Id FROM Table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other Simple way to copy distinct data with multiple columns from one table to other

```
Insert into TBL2 
Select * from (Select COL1, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY COL1 Order By COL1) AS COL2 From TBL1)T
where T.COL2 = 1
```